# Add SUMIFS function into excel formula using C#

Tags: c#, excel

My code :

```
String txt = "SUMIFS('First'!I11:I318; 'First'!B11:B318; A14; 'First'!F11:F318; E14)";
MainWindow.constructCellWithFormula(InsertCellInWorksheet(worksheetPart, "G", lineNumber),
"10",
txt,
CellValues.Number,
1);
```

I don't know why but this formula doesn't work :(
I've an error when I want to open my Excel document.

```
public static Cell constructCellWithFormula(Cell c, string value, string formule, CellValues dataType, uint styleIndex = 0)
    {
        styleIndex = 0;
        Cell cell = c;
        CellFormula cellformula = new CellFormula();
        cellformula.Text = formule;
        CellValue cellValue = new CellValue();
        cellValue.Text = value;
        cell.DataType = dataType;
        cell.Append(cellformula);
        cell.Append(cellValue);
        return cell;
    }
```

Someone knows why?

Comment: Since you aren't showing `InsertCellInWorksheet`and `constructCellWithFormula` it's really hard for us to say.

Comment: InsertCellInWorksheet is here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/office/cc861607.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I should think that you need "=" in front of SUMIFS. Also the criteria need to be "formula-like", like this:

```
String txt = "=SUMIFS('First'!I11:I318; 'First'!B11:B318; \"=A14\"; 'First'!F11:F318; \"=E14\")";
```

What this states is:
*Sum the contents of I11..I318 for rows where the B column equals the content of A14 and the F column equals the content of E14.*

Comment: I've the same error message. It's work into Excel but not in openXML document creating using C#

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution to my problem. SUMIFS function isn't available with an XLS format. So, I can use SUMPRODUCT to do this.